# Items are returned incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need your help. My task is to create 100 divs with pure JavaScript. Each div should have the following functionality: Each div has its own name, like div1, div2, div3 and up to 100. For instance, I click on div31, div45, div89, they move to the top. Now the order of my elements is as follows:

`div89, div45, div31, div1, div2`

at the places where I took the `div` data

- div30 - div32 - div33
- div43 -div44 - div46
- div88 – div90 – div91

When I click again on the moved up items, they should return to their previous positions.
The problem is that when I click on the elements that have risen for me, they return, but in arbitrary places. That is, instead of going back, in our example `div30, div31, div32, div33`, our `div31` can be anywhere. Tell me what is my mistake? Thank you very much

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'div-element';
    div.textContent = 'div' + i;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

const originalPositions = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('div-element')).map((div, index) => index);

const divElements = document.getElementsByClassName('div-element');
for (let i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
    const div = divElements[i];
    let isFirstPosition = false;
    let originalPosition = -1;

    div.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (!isFirstPosition) {
            document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstElementChild);
            isFirstPosition = true;
            originalPosition = i;
        } else {
            const referenceDiv = divElements[originalPositions[originalPosition]];
            document.body.insertBefore(div, referenceDiv.nextElementSibling);
            isFirstPosition = false;
        }
    });
 }
});
```

Comment: If you do this on a piece of paper with 5 items, where you remember their original index, and move 3 of them to the top, and then move the first moved of those three back to its original index, do you see how this logic is wrong?

Comment: @trincot Thank you very much for your attention and response. Can you help me solve this?

Comment: But did you do this exercise on paper? What is your analysis?

Comment: Instead of trying to maintain the `originalPosition` value, can't you dynamically infer the original position based on the `textContent`?  So any time you click on something that isn't "first", you move it to the top.  Then any time you click on something that *is* "first", you read its content and loop over the other elements reading their content until you find where it goes.

Comment: What should happen if you have clicked all elements once in some random order, and then click one of them a second time? Where should it go? What is the logic you really want to implement?

Comment: @trincot When you first click on any section of the element, it should be moved to the first one
position of the body, when you click again on the same element - it is returned to its exit
position
For example, the user clicks on a div that is at position index 5. It
should be rewritten and become the first div in the body.
If the same div is clicked again (now at position index 0), it
must fulfill its initial position with an index of 5.

Comment: Yes, that part I understood, but it is ambiguous. Please answer for the scenario I described.

Comment: @trincot On paper, this logic looks simple, as you would like it to work. However, your answer on how to protect the previous index is impossible to figure out how to implement this. Now there may be a warning that it is advisable not to communicate in the comments. Tell me, this code works well for me, can't I improve mine in any way? If you have an answer, can you show it? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I cannot answer, because the behaviour you want is not clear in **all** cases. I can repeat again what I wrote above, but I suppose you can just reread it? What should happen?

Comment: @trincot I click on random items in the list. I have them rising to the top - the one that was lifted last should be on top. If we click again on any of the raised elements, they go back to where they were before. That is, they stand back in order. I hope I explained correctly)

Comment: You answer to questions I have not asked. OK, I will try one more time before giving up: What If I have `div1 div2 div3 div4 div5` and I click (in this order) `div5 div4 div3` so that I get `div3 div4 div5 div1 div2`, and then I click `div3` again. Should I get `div4 di5 div3 div1 div2` (putting the element at its original index), or `div4 div5 div1 div2 div3` (because it should follow after `div2`)? Or still something else?

Comment: OK, I see you have already accepted an answer. Will not spend more on this. Thanks for having tried to answer my questions.

Comment: @trincot, Mr. Polywhirl gave me the right answer. Thanks for your attention and help) I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not append to the `<body>`. This makes it much harder to move elements around. You should create a container element to hold them.

Now, you should use the `dataset` property for each element to store stateful information like original index and if the element has moved. Note that values in the `dataset` are always retrieved as strings. You will need to convert them back into boolean and integer values to do comparisons.

When reverting back to the original position, you should loop backwards.

```js
const findRefEl = (container, index) => {
  const targetIndex = +index; // Cast to a number
  // Loop backwards
  for (let i = container.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const currentIndex = +container.children[i].dataset.originalIndex;
    if (currentIndex < targetIndex) {
      return container.children[i];
    }
  }
  return container.children[0]; // Default to the first
}

const handleMove = (e) => {
  const div = e.target, containerEl = div.closest('.container');
  if (div.dataset.moved === 'false') {
    containerEl.insertBefore(div, containerEl.firstElementChild);
    div.dataset.moved = 'true';
  } else {
    const ref = findRefEl(containerEl, div.dataset.originalIndex);
    containerEl.insertBefore(div, ref.nextElementSibling);
    div.dataset.moved = 'false';
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const containerEl = document.querySelector('.container');
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'div-element';
    div.textContent = `div${i + 1}`;
    div.dataset.originalIndex = i.toString(); // Track the original index
    div.dataset.moved = false; // Track if it has been moved
    div.addEventListener('click', handleMove);
    containerEl.appendChild(div);
  }
});
```

```css
.div-element {
  border: thin solid grey;
  min-width: 4rem;
  max-width: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div-element:hover {
  background: yellow;
}

.div-element[data-moved="true"] {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, it works as it should)